# How to make my 2d box into a 2d array that I can pull info out of each index?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

There are many questions about how to make a 2d list in python here.
I know that you can initialize one, but I'm unsure how to make a list that can take the form of my code below . The code I have works to make the kind of box I want, but I also want to be able to ask the user if they want to grab from that list, or change a value in it.

```
def main():
    width = int(input("Enter width :: "))
    height = int(input("Enter height :: "))
    char = "-"
    table = []
    for x in range(height):
        print('-'* width)
main()
```

So how do I make it so that I have a 2d array that I can grab index values from, that looks exactly like what this code prints?
The intended output is above but in 2d array style form.
The actual output is just a printed string of what I want, instead of a modifiable object.

Here is a general idea of what the code looks like, if you give a w of 6 and h of 7, this is returned (once again, this is correct, but I want it in an array):

```
------
------
------
------
------
------
------
```

Answer (score 0):

That is what you need:

```
table = [[char]*width for _ in range(height)]
```

You can print it like so:

```
for row in table:
    for c in row:
        print(c, end='')
    print()
```

And you can edit values like so:

```
table[row_index][column_index] = new_value
```

Comment: Hi Evgeny! Doesn't this print on one line though?

Comment: @DrDeletus What do you mean? It does not print anything. It creates 2d array.

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean like if I wanted to print this table out how could I go about making it look like the answer I printed above. Or could I just print it the same way I did above but modify it using the code you gave? Maybe I'm not understanding this completely. I just wanted to modify values at specific rows and columns of the array, then print out the array in a fashion that looks like the printed code I gave above.

Comment: @DrDeletus Updated. Is it what you need?

Comment: I don't know why, but it seems to have printed everything on one line.

Comment: @DrDeletus It works fine for me. check if `print()` on the last line of printing has 4 spaces before it, so it is inside `for row in table:` loop

Comment: Ah yes, I had the print under the wrong for loop. Thank you very much!

Comment: @DrDeletus pls, mark answer as a correct if you think it is